# Correct way of altering JSON:API output

Tags: 9

So just wanted to know the best way to override json api output
beside doing the most dirty hack I can possibly think of:

Beware dirty hacks below ..

```
 public function __construct(
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager,
    UserAuthInterface $user_auth
    ) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->userAuth = $user_auth;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events['kernel.response'] = ['kernelResponse'];
    return $events;
  }


 /**
   * This method is called when the kernel.response is dispatched.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event $event
   *   The dispatched event.
   */
  public function kernelResponse(Event $event) {

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $clonedRequest  = $request->request;

    if (!empty($request) && $request  instanceof Request) {
          if ($request->get('_route') === 'jsonapi.node--page.collection') {
             /// Hack and cry 
            $response_content = $event->getResponse()->getContent();
            $json_data = json_decode($response_content, true);
            $new_content = $json_data['something'] = ['extra hackery here'];
            // re encode this makes me feel dirty. 
            $new_content_encoded = json_encode($new_content, true);
            // Prevent header validation error (triple down on hackey ness) .
            $event->getResponse()->setContent($new_content_encoded);
            $event->getResponse()->headers->set('content-type', 'application/json');
      }
  }
```

I can see jsonapi_extras and jsonapi_resources
i would have thought you would make a new serializer and use that but i got errors
JSONAPI does not support more seriliser's then went down a FieldEnhancer rabbit hole.
could some one please share the best way to do this with out the need to take a shower ?

Comment: Please clarify what your goal is in altering the output, as different alterations will require different approaches.  For example, you might want to rename things (like JSON:API Extras module does) or provide data from multiple entity types from a single resource (like you can do with JSON:API Resources module).  Generally JSON:API is just returning your content as it is already structured in Drupal, so instead of altering it specifically for JSON:API, you should alter the structure itself in Drupal.

Comment: yep have used the Resources module before, what I was doing was just tweaking image urls (image styles) returned  so did not have to make multiple calls in my node.js app i tried consumer_image_styles but could not get any of the node image to return at all for some reason.

Comment: Given the various ways that image styles can be altered, I think it is much safer to use something like Consumer Image Styles than to attempt to roll your own solution by hacking JSON:API.  Setting up the consumers is a bit tricky and not very well documented at present, but the module definitely works (it's part of Contenta, the decoupled drupal distribution) once you get it set up.

Comment: as it turns out i disabled the file--file resource which then on the node resource did not display the image paths... but  still its kinda crap really wish we could somehow hook in and alter the returned data directly instead of having to include it (with image fields a least)